# Can't set boolean value to component inside component that it's inside another component Angular 11.x

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have 3 components,`ComponentX`, `ComponentY` and `ComponentZ`.

**componentx.component.html**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="main-content">
            <p>La la la la</p>
        </div>
        <button (click)="showComponentY">Show next component</button>
        <app-componenty *ngIf="componentYng"></app-componenty>
    </div>
</div>
```

**componenty.component.html**

```html
    <div class="column">
        <div class="main-content">
            <p> Bla bla bla</p>
        </div>
        <button (click)="showComponentZ">Show next component</button>
        <app-componentz *ngIf="componentZng"></app-componentz>
    </div>
```

**componentz.component.html**

```html
    <div class="column">
        <div class="main-content">
            <p> Bla bla bla</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
```

For every component.ts, I'm using the same method to show the next component.
**componentx.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-componentx',
  templateUrl: './componentx.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./componentx.component.scss',
              './componentx.component.css']
})
export class ComponentXComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() informacao!:boolean;
  constructor() { }
  componentYng : boolean = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  showComponentY(){
    if(this.componentYng === false){
      this.componentYng = true;
    }else{
      this.componentYng = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**componenty.component.ts** is exactly the same, just changing **componentYng** for **componentZng**, **showComponentY** for **showComponentZ** and **componentz.component.ts doesn't still have anything.**

The methods are working to hide and show, when I click to show the **Component Y**, it works perfectly, but when I click to show **Component** Z in **Component Y**, the **Component Z** appears and hide, but seems to get out of the row's align. Also, if set all the components to appear instantly in the Component X, it works perfectly.

For example:

**componentx.component.html**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="main-content">
            <p>La la la la</p>
        </div>       
        <app-componenty></app-componenty>
        <app-componentz></app-componentz>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, all the components will be kept align.

Comment: You are using `<app-componenty>` inside `componenty.component.html`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Actually no. app-componenty is inside of componentx.component.html. I've typed it wrong. Let me edit it.

Comment: Is it possible to create a stackblitz example so that I can have something to work on?